# Download / upload file using the Add-On SDK

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am currently trying to download a small binary file from the web, in order to upload that to another website, both using the API.

Previous versions seemed to have the "file" API module for such purposes, but I can't see anything similar as of the latest (1.14).

The file to be downloaded would be saved in some form of cache (browser cache, preferably), its path stored somewhere, to be then uploaded to another URL via POST.

How would I go about it, when the process should happen completely in the background?

I checked out the [how to download a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files) page, but can't figure out where to download.
Is there a variable URI for the "Downloads" directory, and does a regular Add-On has write privileges in it?. 
This is important, because the add-on must be able to function properly on various platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pref, `browser.download.lastDir`, which should work for windows/mac as it will be saved in the OS format.  However the pref may not always be set if the person has never downloaded anything before.  In that case you'll have to build the directory yourself.

```
var dir = require("sdk/preferences/service").get('browser.download.lastDir');
```

To build the directory yourself you're going to have to go a little deeper.  Check this article on MDN about [File I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O) which has examples.  The `DfltDwnld` key should give you the directory you want.

Your add-on will have write permissions to everything Firefox has write permission to.